# Difference of standard publish and adding cloud services with vs2012

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, publish, azure-web-roles, webdeploy

I wonder if someone can help? I'm trying to deploy a mvc app to azure and have followed the what appeared to be simple instructions of selecting publish from my mvc app and using the imported azure profile.  This all worked fine and with a couple of tweaks the site is working, after some testing I'm getting a 500 error, I've set the logging on but this doesn't help much.
After looking around I see that I can rdp to the site but this requires a web role and a different sort of publish am I missing something from the standard publish or do I need to add the cloud service stuff to my project?

Comment: Is your site currently published as an Azure Website?

Comment: seems to be a Web Site!

Comment: I just used the vs publish option as the azure tutorials sugest